# Use second network interface as private network

Tags: networking, router, routing

I've got two RJ-45 network interfaces built into my motherboard, and the second one is currently of no use to me. I would like to set it up so that I can plug routers into it and then access their configuration pages before attaching them directly to our business network. From what I've read, it seems I need to set up temporary routes via the command prompt when I do this, but if these temporary routes would be overriding routes that are necessary for standard network operation, I suppose I might as well just unplug my primary connection and use it for router configuration.

Is there a way to keep my primary network connection (to the business network) active, and route specific traffic to the second connection?

```
My internal IP: 10.1.1.72
Subnet mask: 255.255.0.0
New router default IP: 10.1.1.1 (would be connected to second NIC)
```

10.1.1.1 is a significant address on our business network, so that is where I fear this will all break down. My motivation behind all of this is I would like to not have to take my system completely off of our network when I need to do router configuration. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with doing this. The caveat being that if the routers default ip address is 10.1.1.1 and that ip address is in use on the production network then you'll need to add a specific route to that ip address for the interface that's connected to the router and you'll need to delete that route when you're finished. You also won't be able to access the device/host at 10.1.1.1 on the production network while this route is in place.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I can figure out the right syntax for setting up the route I suppose a temporary route that only conflicts with a single host on the production network would be better than complete disconnect. After a little more googling, I've found this: http://www.howtogeek.com/117890/how-to-force-an-application-to-use-a-specific-network-card/ which seems to force a single applications communications through a designated NIC.

Comment: I'd rather use the `route` command then some dodgy hack I found on the internet. there's no `conflict` involved. Your computer will be able to communicate with one host at 10.1.1.1 or the other, but not both simultaneously.

Comment: alright, I've fumbled with the route command and can't seem to get it right. If I've set my second card to IP: 10.1.8.1, what route do I need to add so that 10.1.1.1 goes through the second card (interface 12)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second NIC for a private network, as long as both are in different subnets.

Your current NIC is in the 10.0.0.0/255.255.0.0 subnet.

Typically, consumer routers will want you to connect to 192.168.0.1/255.255.0.0, 192.168.1.1/255.255.0.0, 192.168.0.254/255.255.0.0, or 192.168.1.254/255.255.0.0.  This does not conflict with your first NIC's subnet.

So really all you need to do is assign an appropriate static IP to your second NIC.  Do not assign a DNS server.  This should not change your default gateway, so Internet-destined traffic will be unaffected.

You should not need to mess with any routes or touch your routing table.  Your system knows by virtue of you assigning your NIC the IP address 192.168.0.1 and subnet mask 255.255.0.0, for example, that it can reach anything 192.168.X.X through that NIC.

Now, if you are working with a router that wants you to connect to 10.X.X.X for setup, you're in a bit of trouble.  Fortunately these are rare, and there is a silver lining.

I would imagine such a router would want you to connect to 10.0.0.1 for setup.  Your current IP is 10.1.X.X with a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0.  This does NOT conflict with 10.0.X.X with a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0.  So you can, if needed, assign your second NIC 10.0.0.50/255.255.0.0, for example, and not experience problems ...

... *unless* you do have machines on a 10.0.X.X subnet that you need to reach.  Your system will prefer the directly connected interface by default, so traffic destined to 10.0.50.50., for example, will go out the second NIC.  In that case you will want to mess with the routing table, but it may be easier under Windows to just unplug your corporate-facing NIC for a while.

Comment: Yeah, most of the business class routers we have been getting have had default IPs in our already in use range. I keep agonizing over this, and continue looping around to "maybe I should just quit whining and unplug."

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with certainty due to the fact that you cannot control the initial/factory-default IP/subnet assigned to the new router until after you've set the router up. It's the "chicken vs the egg" problem. What you can do is unplug your main network and plug the new router in, configure the new router to a different IP and subnet as the first thing you do, and then plug your main network back in while you configure the rest of the new router on it's new IP/subnet.

Personally, I keep a laptop on the side of my desk to do this sort of thing, and anything else where I need to connect to ethernet away from the main company network. It takes all of a couple minutes to reprogram the router to a non-conflicting IP/subnet then switch it over to the main network to configure everything else and test.